# Can't apt-get upgrade

Tags: apt, php

So apt-get tells me to use -f install

```
guy@server:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.13.0-32 linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-35 linux-headers-3.13.0-35-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-36 linux-headers-3.13.0-36-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-37 linux-headers-3.13.0-37-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-39 linux-headers-3.13.0-39-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-40 linux-headers-3.13.0-40-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-44 linux-headers-3.13.0-44-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-48 linux-headers-3.13.0-48-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-49 linux-headers-3.13.0-49-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic linux-image-3.13.0-35-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-36-generic linux-image-3.13.0-37-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-39-generic linux-image-3.13.0-40-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-44-generic linux-image-3.13.0-48-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-49-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-35-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-36-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-37-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-39-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-40-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-44-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-48-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-49-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.13.0-48-generic linux-image-3.13.0-49-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-57-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc-3.13.0 linux-source-3.13.0 linux-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.13.0-48-generic linux-image-3.13.0-49-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-57-generic
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 77 not upgraded.
69 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/45.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 127 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 384965 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.13.0-57-generic_3.13.0-57.95_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-3.13.0-57-generic (3.13.0-57.95) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-57-generic_3.13.0-57.95_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/System.map-3.13.0-57-generic' to '/boot/System.map-3.13.0-57-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Br
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-57-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-57-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-57-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-57-generic
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.13.0-48-generic_3.13.0-48.80_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-3.13.0-48-generic (3.13.0-48.80) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-48-generic_3.13.0-48.80_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-48-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-48-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No sp
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Br
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-48-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-48-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-48-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-48-generic
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.13.0-49-generic_3.13.0-49.83_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-3.13.0-49-generic (3.13.0-49.83) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-49-generic_3.13.0-49.83_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-49-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-49-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No sp                                                          ace left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Br                                                          oken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-49-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-49-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-49-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-49-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-57-generic_3.13.0-57.95_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-48-generic_3.13.0-48.80_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-49-generic_3.13.0-49.83_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I fix this? I've tried the autoremove and still won't let me update or add new software. Please help!

Answer (score 3):

```
the error message indicates a disk full error
```

This is the source of your problem. You need to free up disk space before you can do anything else. Try to free up at least a gigabyte.

Part of your problem is the large number of old kernels that have built up. Each one could be responsible for 200-300 MB.

The command is:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

by itself. Don't try anything else at the same time.

Be aware of 2 things:

1. You might need to free some disk space before doing the autoremove. It may need some free temp space in order to proceed.
2. Removing that many kernels in one shot will take a very long time. Be sure you have the time to let it run without needing to interrupt it.

Comment: That can't be true, I'll try autoremove anyhow.

Sorry can't seem to figure out how to use askubuntu. I'm trying to paste in some output from df aswell as the welcome message, it says there is tons of free space.

Comment: Do you have a separate /boot partition?

Answer (score 0):

You were right. The /boot partition is at 100%, however I can't autoremove because it still says there is unmet dependencies. So I will remove them manually and I will post again to find out which ones I can remove safely.